# Runtime error with multiple partial refresh

Tags: xpages

Per help me getting a single XSP.partialRefreshGet to work.  That is working fine for me noe. Thank you.  Now I need to get multiple refreshes to work:

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{txtRateType}", {
   onComplete: function() {
    XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{CurrentBalancesSection}", {
        onComplete: function() {
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{PricingSection}}", {});
        }
    });
 }
});
```

I get a run time error.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the id part again (and you had an extra curly brace), Bruce :-)

```
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:txtRateType}", {
   onComplete: function() {
    XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:CurrentBalancesSection}", {
        onComplete: function() {
            XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:PricingSection}", {});
        }
    });
 }
});
```

This is client side JS and the functions need client side ids. You use {id: to tell XPages to return the client side id of a server side component.

Comment: Well now I have other issues. :)   But I will create a new post.  I will get the hang of this partial refresh thing if it kills you. :)