# How do I partial refresh elements which were rendered before my result was calculated?

Tags: xpages

I need (a list of entry) values from a repeat control in a combo box above that control. 
The control is filtered dynamically by user input, the combo box (of course) always shows the result of the previous filtering. 
How can I force the combo box to refresh AFTER the repeat is rendered?

Must be simple - but I do not find a solution

thx in advance, 
Uwe

Comment: You can do a 2nd partial refresh in the onComplete event of the first partial refresh (assuming you do a partial refresh of the repeat control)

Comment: the onChange events in the combobox(es) do the partial refresh of the panel containing the repeat control. The rc has SSJS as binding, in which I fill viewScope variables. These vars are bound to comboboxes above the repeat. 
Where do I find the onComplete event of the 1st partial refresh?

Comment: Can you explain a little more. The rendering of the repeat control doesn't change any data. So I presume somewhere else the user makes a selection that leads to the re-rendering of the repeat control and the combo box. Besides Per's approach, could you just put both elements into a panel and refresh that one (or a div)?

Comment: See this answer for examples of chained partial refreshes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13276793/785061

Comment: @stwissel: at the moment my repeat has a data source sth like:
var myresult:NotesViewEntryCollection = viwLUP.getAllEntriesByKey(getFilter(),true); (//-- viwLUP is the view bound to the sorrounding panel)
var myfilter = getSearchFilter();

if (hasContent(myfilter)) {
myresult.FTSearch(myfilter);
}
so it changes the data and should change the selectitems in the combobox (djFilteringSelect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find examples of doing the partial refresh in onComplete (and a little more) in e.g. these articles: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh and http://www.timtripcony.com/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-84B6VP.

That way you could implement what Per suggests.

Comment: sorry for my inexperience, but HOW do I add the onChange event to a partial refresh, selected in the designer's UI? I see in the source:       <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true"
       refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pAuftraege"
       id="eventHandler4">. 
Do I have to add sth there?

Comment: Oh yes, when you have the event selected go to "All properties" and scroll down to "events". Here you find onComplete (and onStart) as mentioned in the articles above. It can be a little tricky to find first time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the classic "cascading filter" (like Pick a country, second box shows the states, 3rd box the cities and the repeat shows the customers there).

I would pack the whole block into a panel or div and refresh the div on any of the combo boxes onChange event. On the server side have one object (SsJS or Java) that provides the select values for all your dropdowns, so you clear "following" dropdowns when the leading box invalidates the selected value.

The second approach as outlined by Per would be to cascade the partial refreshes. That approach has the advantage to repaint less of the screen (precise targeting of refresh), but makes more network calls (not a problem in an Intranet, might be an issue in high latency environments I live in).

If you have more than one dropdown to refresh the div/panel approach is less work.

Let us know how it goes

Comment: the whole block is already packed in one panel, BUT the repeat renders AFTER the djFilteringSelect controls.

Comment: The "rendering" phase doesn't matter as much as the computation of the data. You have distinct phases and you "only" need to make sure that your view and your comboboxes derive the values from the same source. So the boxes would already know what the UI of the table will get in data.