# Can an XPage have multiple rendering conditions

Tags: javascript, xpages

I have an Xpage with a djTabContainer and the tab container holds several Custom Controls.  One of the Custom Controls only has the contents rendered upon meeting a certain condition as shown here;

```
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("conCapRev").getValue()   
== "External”}]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

I want to have the Custom Controls contents rendered now upon meeting one of two conditions, where basically the rendering tag has an or in the Javascript.  If this is not possible can there be two rendering tags?

I should mention that the rendering (or not rendering) of the tabbed Custom Control should occur when the document is being created and not just after it has been created and saved.

The code above works for this scenario.  When I change getComponent for document1 as shown in the next XML tag it also works with no errors.

```
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getValue("conCapRev")   
== "External"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

But when I add in the second condition as shown below it does not work and the Custom Control is always rendered.  How can I solve this please?

```
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getValue("conCapRev") == "External" 
|| document1.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

To perhaps add more information to make the issue clearer - during the initiation of a "Contract" document the user decides if the conCapRev field will be "Internal" or "External", then continuing with the Contracts general information the user selects a value for Tender Type (the ConTenderType field) from a possible list one of which is "Extension".  The user then completes at least the Workflow tab with many fields and at this point the Contract can be saved or exit (discard without saving). Before or after the Contract is saved the user can go to another tab named Baseline which will NOT be rendered if the conCapRev field is "External" OR the conTenderType field is "Extension".

Comment: Use always `===` and `!==` for comparison in JavaScript to avoid unexpected type conversions. That is not the issue here though...

Comment: Thanks Knut.  This is good information

Comment: Are you sure you have the logic right? Can you update your question with an example of the field contents from a document and what you expect?

Comment: The logic of this application is complicated - overly complicated in fact (and I did not build it and I have never been trained in Xpages).  The document being created has a vast amount of fields due to having a tab that is a workflow that covers over 50 fields alone, so to show you the fields being populated would be an enormous input.  I will try and elaborate the question above with more information without having to list what would be about 80 fields for a document record being created

Comment: Focus on what is not working. That is: `document1.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension"` returns always true. Test only this condition. First, show "conTenderType" item in a computed field. Contains it really "Extension"? Next, if so, add the render condition to the computed field. Is it still visible? Maybe you use an alias for "Extension" internally...

Comment: @KnutHerrmann - I did as you suggested and looked at what was NOT working, that being the document1.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension" and it works on its own - at least in a certain sense. In the Baseline tab I changed the rendering tag to be as follows <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("conTenderType").getValue() != "Extension"}]]></xp:this.rendered> and this makes the Baseline not rendered in the Contract but ONLY AFTER I save the Contract. Could it be soemthing to do with the OR condition then in the multiple rendering statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in your last question's sentence that you want Baseline Custom Control

```
NOT be rendered if 
the conCapRev field is "External" OR 
the conTenderType field is "Extension"
```

or to say it the other way

```
be rendered if 
the conCapRev field is NOT "External" AND 
the conTenderType field is NOT "Extension"
```

So, your rendering condition should be then

```
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    document1.getValue("conCapRev") != "External" &&
    document1.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension"
}]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

*Update after some commenting:*

After changing conTenderType's value you have to partially refresh

- the conTenderType's listBox
- the ContractBaselinePanel panel
- the ContractDetailPanel panel

You can use cascaded CSJS XSP calls to do so. Make sure you don't try to refresh an element which has the rendered property as if it's not rendered it can't be refresh (because it is not there on client side).

```
<xp:listBox
    id="listBoxConTenderType"
    value="#{document1.conTenderType}">
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="Extension">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem
        itemLabel="...">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onchange"
        submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
           XSP.partialRefreshPost("#{id:listBoxConTenderType}", {
               onComplete: function() {
                   XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:ContractBaselinePanel}", {
                      onComplete: function() {
                          XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:ContractDetailPanel}", {});
                      } 
                   });
              }
           });]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:listBox>
<xp:panel
    id="ContractBaselinePanel">
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            document1.getValue("conCapRev") != "External" &&
            document1.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension"
        }]]></xp:this.rendered>
        ...your Baseline Custom Control...
    </xp:panel>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Yes I checked that Knut.  The conTenderType is a ComboBox and the list item Extension also has the value of Extension.  Although I noticed the conTenderType comboBox has an onChange event with a partial refresh on the ContractDetailPanel that the combo box resides in.  Would a full refresh make any difference?

Comment: The control with that rendered code should be included in partial refresh. This way the rendered code is executed again after changing "conTenderType".

Comment: Okay, I will leave the setting as partial refresh.

Comment: Knut - Thanks so far. I can confirm the document1 is the data source.  I am not in work now till Tuesday 24th now so will try again then.  Currently the rendered tag reads <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getValue("conCapRev") == "External" || document1.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension"}]]></xp:this.rendered> and the Baseline Custom Control is not rendered if the Contract is External but is still rendered if Extension tender type is selected. I am also able to confirm the value of Extension is correct when retrieved programatically in Java code as "Extension"

Comment: Hmm!! Yes the change from the OR to the AND works but again ONLY after I save the Contract.  Previously when it was only using the condition <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("conCapRev").getValue() != "External"}]]></xp:this.rendered> the rendering of the Baseline Custom Control happened as the value was changed from External to Internal.

Comment: Add an onchange event to your conTenderType field and partially refresh the panel which contains Baseline Custom Control include (similar to conCapRev?).

Comment: The conTenderType field already has an onChange event to partial refresh the panel itself is in (not sure why the designer did this) but when I change it to "ContractBaselinePanel" and run the application, when I change conCapRev to External a warning states it cannot find the view containing "ContractBaselinePanel"!!!

Comment: It can't find it because it is not rendered :) - surround your "ContractBaselinePanel" by a `<xp:panel id="baselinePanel"> ... </xp:panel>` and change refreshId to "baselinePanel".

Comment: All the components in the Baseline tab are already contained with <xp:panel id="ContractBaselinePanel"> ... </ xp:panel> so do you mean I change <xp:panel id="ContractBaselinePanel"> to <xp:panel id="BaselinePanel" refreshId="baselinePanel"> and change the onChange event to baselinePanel?

Comment: No, don't change it. For which control is the rendered code?

Comment: Currently conTenderType performs a partial refresh on the ContractDetailPanel that conTenderType resides in at an onChange event.  I think we need to include the ContractBaselinePanel as a partial refresh at an onChange event

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to partially refresh the ContractBaselinePanel panel so that the rendered property gets calculated again.

Comment: So going back to your previous comment - how do I get it to identify the ContractBaselinePanel?  Also can I still partially refresh the ContractDetailPanel at the same time?

Comment: Thank you so much. This now appears to work.  Can I ask why is it necessary to have the nested <xp:panel>??  I had found this URL today which was along the same lines but hadn't time to attempt it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276521/runtime-error-with-multiple-partial-refresh

Comment: You're welcome. The nested <xp:panel> is for the rendered property which can contain several controls and all effected by rendered property then. If you have only *one* control e.g. your Baseline Custom Control then you can add the rendered property to this CC <xc:Baseline> ... </xc:Baseline> and don't need the additional panel.

Comment: Do you know any good online XPages training source you can recommend. My company will not pay for training and I will never get familiar with XPages doing just "bits and pieces" here and there.  I have other technologies to support too.  Thanks

Comment: I recommend you the book "Mastering XPages Second Edition". It contains sample databases for all parts of the book and is available as eBook (a bit cheaper) too. Videos from NotesIn9 are always worth the time to watch http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Videos.xsp . Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do what you are trying to do. If the two components are actually bound to data source fields, then you should ask the data source for the value instead of the component.

So try this instead (assuming that your data source is called "document"):

```
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
document.getValue("conCapRev") == "External" 
|| document.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension"
}]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

Comment: Thanks.  The two fields for the conditions are certainly bound to database fields.  I will try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: Hmm!! I thought this would work Per.  However, I get the error "Script interpreter error, 'document' not found".  I am confused because it should recognise the document and the two fields are certainly in the Notes document database

Comment: What's the name of your data source? Apparently not "document" but perhaps "document1" (which is the default name)

Comment: Per - I looked at code and yes, it seems to use document1 for the processing of the current record and when I changed document to document1 there were no errors.  But still no joy.  I have updated my question with more information

Comment: Per - Thanks so far. I can confirm the document1 is the data source.  I am not in work now till Tuesday 24th now so will try again then.  Currently the rendered tag reads <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getValue("conCapRev") == "External" || document1.getValue("conTenderType") != "Extension"}]]></xp:this.rendered> and the Baseline Custom Control is not rendered if the Contract is External but is still rendered if Extension tender type is selected. I am also able to confirm the value of Extension is correct when retrieved programatically in Java code